# Find all records where a column is either equal to string A or string B using kusto query language

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to find all records in a table where one of the columns `CounterName` contains a certain kind of string and another column `InstanceName` has the value equivalent to either string `C:` or string `D:`.

The below query works appropriately and returns the required records/results:

```
Perf
| search CounterName:"Free*bytes" and (InstanceName=="C:" or InstanceName=="D:")
```

However, in the above query, we need to repeat the `InstanceName` twice. So I attempted another query (*shared below*) which attempts to do the same, but it does not return any records (*NO RESULTS FOUND*):

```
Perf
| search CounterName:"Free*bytes" and InstanceName==("C:" or "D:")
```

Why is the second query not return any results? Is it because of the expression `("C:" or "D:")` which would evaluate to a boolean?

Is there a way I can search multiple strings in a column (*and select that record if any string is present*) without having to repeat the column name (*like we had to repeat in the first query*)?

We can run the above queries online on [Log Analytics](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade) in the demo section if needed (*however, it may require login*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `or` operator is meant to be used with Boolean expressions. Using it with strings does not evaluate one result or the other.

To achieve what you are asking, try the `in` operator instead.

```
Perf
| search CounterName:"Free*bytes" and InstanceName in ("C:","D:")
```